# Pip: installing a newer module version with `--user` option

Tags: python, pip, versioning

*Scenario:*

A python package abc is installed as a system package e.g. to `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/...` (either as `sudo pip install abc` or via the system package manager).

A higher version of the abc package is installed with `pip` as a user package: `pip install abc --user`.

Which version will be effective for that specific user? (ie when a script contains `import abc`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever one is in the users $PATH.

`which abc` will show you which one will run, if you simply ran `abc`.

`echo $PATH` will show, in order, the directories that will be checked for the executable with the first location it's found, being used.

If you're within a pipenv then this may modify the behaviour, but the above statements still stand, you just might find you have a different $PATH.